# Dont know how to solve error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, pyodbc

I am trying to fetch the result from the OptionMenu when it is clicked. However I keep getting the error.

```
>Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3440, in __call__
    self.__var.set(self.__value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I don't know how to solve this as I want to be able to find the value that the user selects so I can use it within another function.

If it helps the words stored in the database are city names.

```
def destination_selected() :
    selection = destination_choice.get()
    print(selection)

def destination_dropdownbox_GUI():
    destination = []
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Destination FROM FlightTable ')
    row = str(cursor.fetchone())
    x = 0
    for x in row :
        row = str(cursor.fetchone())
        row = re.sub(r'\W+', '', row)
        destination.append(row)
        if row == 'None' :
            break
    destination.pop()
    print(destination)
    temp_dest = []
    temp_dest = destination
    print(temp_dest)
    destination_dropdownbox = OptionMenu(window, *temp_dest,command = destination_selected).pack()
```

I expect an output of a city name. EG `'Oslo'`

Comment: Do you have any Destination named 'None' ? Why you compare the row to 'None' and not to `None`?

Comment: I don't see any reference to `.set` in the code you have presented. Please edit your question to include the full traceback (the bit that begins `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends at the error message).

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you're calling the `set` method on a string, and strings don't have a `set` method. Why are you calling `set` on a string?  Also, none of the code you posted will cause this error. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: This is the full error given when I run the code                                              Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3440, in __call__
    self.__var.set(self.__value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'    - @BoarGules

Comment: @BryanOakley the code wouldn't work if I didn't assign the cursor.fetchone() as a str() as the widget came up blank without an OptionMenu.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the `OptionMenu` widget you'll see that after the `master` argument you must supply a `variable`. This parameter must be set to one of the special tkinter variables (`StringVar`, etc).

You aren't giving it a proper variable in this argument position, so tkinter is using the string you gave it as the variable. When you change the value, tkinter will call the `set` method. However, since you are passing a string rather than a variable, you get the error that `str` does not have a method named `set`.

The solution is to give the `OptionMenu` a variable. I'm guessing you've already defined this variable since your `destination_selected` method calls `destination_choice.get()`.

Assuming that `destination_choice` is a special tkinter variable, you need to define your `OptionMenu` like this:

```
OptionMenu(window, destination_choice, *temp_dest,command = destination_selected).pack()
```